# what should be the type of errors while passing it as prop useform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have useform hook , where I am getting an errors object. So I am trying to pass it to other componenet.

```
 const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    control,
    formState: { errors, isDirty, isValid }
  } = useForm<CampaignForm>({
    mode: 'all',
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      [FormFields.StartDate]: null,
      [FormFields.EndDate]: null,
      [FormFields.StartTime]: null,
      [FormFields.EndTime]: null,
      [FormFields.Locations]: `${strings.campaign.createCampaign.allRetailLocation}`
    }
```

})

```
  <Campaigon erros={errors} register={register}/>
```

interface is :

```
interface ICampaign {
  register: any
  errors: any
}
```

here, I am using `any`as a type for both. So, what should be the type for register and errors.

Thanks for the help.